# Random factor for simulating a Poisson distribution with a tick-tick simulation

Tags: math, random, simulation, probability, poisson

I've got a program that simulates events happening.  I have the following constraints:

- The distribution should approximate a [Poisson distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_distribution), i.e., independent events occurring at a fixed rate.
- At time 1000 ticks, the event should have happened 100 times (on average).  (1000 and 100 are placeholders; the real numbers are determined experimentally from the real-world system I'm trying to model.)

I'm currently using code of the following form:

```
def tick():
    doMaintenance()
    while random() < 0.1:
        eventHappens()
```

I use a `while` instead of an `if` to simulate the idea that these events are independent.  Otherwise, there would be no chance of two events occurring in the same tick.  However, I suspect that means that the `random() < 0.1` (where `random` returns a number in the half-open range `[0.0, 1.0)`) is slightly inaccurate.  (It's okay that I'm quantizing the event occurrence time.)

Can somebody suggest the correct `random() < f` constant to use if I want (in the general case) a Poisson distribution such that at time `t` there will be event count `e`?  I believe that such a constant `f` exists, but its derivation is not obvious to me.

I'm putting this in `stackoverflow.com` so I can conveniently talk in coding terms and because I'm using a tick-tick simulation which is more familiar to numerical simulation programmers than mathematicians.  If this is something more appropriate in `math.stackexchange.com`, though, let me know.

Comment: Language preference? Because there are plenty of languages where Poisson distributions are readily available, e.g. [C++](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/poisson_distribution). That said, the biggest problem I see is that you entirely ignore the possibility of **two** events, which is of course quite likely (~1%).

Comment: Have you considered dropping the fixed increment time advance and going to an event scheduling mechanism?  Then you could use exponential inter-event times and the events happen when they happen.  Fixed increment time advance is [known to create modeling artifacts](http://www.informs-sim.org/wsc11papers/218.pdf), i.e., behaviors in the model that deviate from real-world behaviors.

Comment: @pjs isn't i a Poisson process? So @Piquan has to sample number of events first in time interval `t` with the rate of 100/1000 via Poisson distribution, and then place events uniformly

Comment: @SeverinPappadeux A Poisson process is a counting process with exponentially distributed times between occurrences.  That's the distribution you also get for the distance between uniformly distributed points, believe it or not.

Answer (score 0):

As MSalters pointed out in comments, even with λ = 100 / 1000 = 0.1, there's a real possibility of having more than one occurrence in a single tick of your clock.  I generated Poisson cumulative probabilities for the given λ—these show the progressive rarity of multiple events in a single tick. You can use them to determine the right number of events via an if/else construct:

```
u = random()
if u ≤ 0.904837418
   // 0 events
else if u ≤ 0.9953211598
   // 1 event
else if u ≤ 0.9998453469
   // 2 events
else if u ≤ 0.9999961532
   // 3 events
else if u ≤ 0.9999999233
   // 4 events
else if u ≤ 0.9999999987
   // 5 events
else
   // 6 events
```

Since the probabilities of more than 6 events are below 10<sup>-10</sup>, they can probably be safely ignored unless you're doing a ridiculous number of time ticks.  You can reduce the number of cases if you're not worried about the rarer cases with higher counts.

I'd still recommend an event scheduling approach with exponential inter-event times (with the same λ)—let the events happen when they happen—but the approach outlined above will work if you just gotta stick with time steps.